# Hide all other sibling div onclick

Tags: jquery, onclick, hide, slidetoggle, siblings

In my page there are lists like what is given below.

```
<li class="select">
  <div class="type"><span class="icon_word_small bgpos"></span></div>
  <div class="docu"> <span class="fade"><a href="">Study on Clinical Research Market in AMEA</a> / 24 July 2011</span></div>
  <div class="colu"> <span class="fade"><a href="">Fairleign</a>, <a href="">Felder</a> & 2 more</span></div>
  <div class="status"><span class="fade"><span class="dark">Public</span> [2 Views 1 Downloads]</span></div>
  <div class="data_options"><a href="#" class="itemDelete">DELETE</a> </div> <!-- row hover options here-->
      <!-- popup starts here-->
    <div class="data_popup data_delete"><span class="tip"></span>Are you sure want to delete this file?
    <div class="cfix"></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="deletebutton"></a></li>
    <li><a href="">No,Keep this file</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
        <!-- popup ends here--> 
  <div class="cfix"></div>
</li>

<li>
  <div class="type"><span class="icon_word_small bgpos"></span></div>
  <div class="docu"> <span class="fade"><a href="">Study on Clinical Research Market in AMEA</a> / 24 July 2011</span></div>
  <div class="colu"> <span class="fade"><a href="">Fairleign</a>, <a href="">Felder</a> & 2 more</span></div>
  <div class="status"><span class="fade"><span class="dark">Public</span> [2 Views 1 Downloads]</span></div>

  <div class="data_options"><a href="#" class="itemShare">SHARE</a></div>  <!-- row hover options here-->
    <!-- popup starts here-->
   <div class="data_popup data_share"><span class="tip"></span><h3>Share</h3>
   <br>
  <p> <input type="checkbox" /> All in our Company</p>
     <p> <input type="checkbox" /> All in Department</p>
           <p> <input type="checkbox" id="sharetick"/> Shared with Specific People</p>
           <div id="textareamsg1"><p><textarea class="resizable" id=""></textarea></p> </div>
           <p> <input type="checkbox" id="nonsharetick"/> Do not share with specific people</p>
             <div id="textareamsg2"><p><textarea class="resizable dark" name="textarea" id="" placeholder="Type names to share document, to share with 
many seperate names with commas"></textarea></p></div>

    <div class="cfix"></div>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="okbutton"></a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cancel</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
      <!-- popup ends here-->
  <div class="cfix"></div>
</li>
```

I'm using this to show/hide div.dataDelete, itemShare

```
$('.itemDelete').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("li").find('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});

$('.itemShare').live('click', function() {
    $(this).closest("li").find('.data_delete').slideToggle('medium');
});
```

on clicking any other links, i need to hide all other open divs( both itemDelete and itemShare). Also I have a doubt in the above code. My client says it is toggling twice sometimes.. I did not experience that in any browsers. Is there any chance that this could occur with the code above or is he coded that wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like:

```
$(".data_options a").live("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".data_popup").slideUp();
    $(this).closest(".select").find(".data_popup").stop(true, false).slideDown();
});
```

The link you are click are both inside: `.data_options`. So we can use that as a reference, not we find all `.data_popup` which contains all DIV's you want to `slideUp`, except for the current one, you wan't to slide that one down.

If it toggles twice, it might be bound twice? Or the do a double click instead of a single click. With above code, current item will always go open instead of toggle.

Comment: Updated, made a mistake with `.parent()` which was the `data_options` instead of the `.select`

Comment: i have updated content with the exact code. in your code itemDelete is poping out on one click, but not hiding. on second click <span class="tip"></span> is hiding instead of it. Nothing happens to itemShare, no popout.

Comment: Yeah currently it does not toggle, then you have to change `.slideDown()` to `slideToggle()`. But wan't it the idea to close all other `.data_popup` elements? I do not touch `.tip` inside this code? Maybe that's why your customer says it's toggling twice, cus it's somewhere else in your code?

Comment: i need to hide all others on first click and show only current div.And  to hide current on second click,. I donno how .tip is hiding. no other code is in der.. 

with previous code showing and hiding wer perfect. no prob with .tip

Comment: i figured it out. everything work perfectly except span.tip. this is disappearing on second click. it is absolutely positioned. is der any problem with that?

Comment: Not in the Javascript, maybe in the CSS. Does it got a left, top CSS properties and does the parent have a `position: Relative`?

Comment: the li is retalive positioned. data_options, data_popup, tip is absolute. top and right locations are specified.

Comment: when i click on the same link for the second time only this happens.. if i click somewhere else for second time no-problem at all..

Comment: problem with .tip is within this code `$(".data_popup").slideUp();` this slides up and does not open back i guess. any alternative?

if we use .hide(), .tip problem is solved, but it does not hides, as the next line contain slideToggle().

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
var q = 0;
$('.itemDelete, .itemShare').live('click',
function() {
    if (q == 1) {
        q = 0;
        $(this).parent().next('.data_delete, .data_share').slideToggle();
    } else {
        q = 1;
        $('.data_delete, .data_share').not($(this).parent().next('.data_delete, .data_share')).slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Comment: no :( onclick a div, 2 ~ 3 other divs are popping out along with current one.